# Why is only half of my label displayed? [WPF]

Tags: wpf, label

I have a grid in a WPF window, and that contains a label in its first column. I have applied a SkewTransform for the label. If I reduce the column width the label is displayed half

[Screenshot](http://freephotoupload.net/view-673_Lable.jpg)

[alt text http://freephotoupload.net/images/673_Lable.jpg](http://freephotoupload.net/images/673_Lable.jpg)

I'm expecting it to display `Prashant`, my main aim is to reduce extra white space next to the label

XAML Code

```
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="146.334" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="94.666" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Name="label1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Content="Prashant">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                        <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

any suggestions Please....

Comment: What is you "Custom" namespace for? looks like you are not using ordinary Transgorm. As GreenReign says use LayOutTransform to solve your issue

Comment: Yeah, I deleted the `Custom:` namespace stuff, then the code above worked as described.

Comment: I have designed it in Blend, so it added autometically..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `LayoutTransform` instead of a `RenderTransform`.

In WPF, `RenderTransforms` are performed on controls after they have been laid out.

In your case, the `Label` is being cut short by the width of the column, first; then, the RenderTransform is applied (the rotate is the only one that does anything), resulting it the odd-looking `Label`.

A `LayoutTransform` is done before a control is laid out.

Like this:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="146.334" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="94.666" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label 
        Name="label1" 
        Content="Prashant"
        Margin="0"  
        Width="Auto" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Label.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Label.LayoutTransform>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```